# How to split comma separated string using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to split a comma separated string with JavaScript. How?

Comment: Does any of these any of these answers produce trimmed values? They're not.

Comment: @NK The OP didn't ask about trimming the values, though.  Splitting on `','` is similar enough to splitting on `'~'` that it seems like this really is a duplicate.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, ideally splitting csv should produce a splitted and trimmed output

Comment: @NK I'm not aware of an authoritative standard for CSV which states this (but there might be such a thing;  I'm just not aware of it), but even if there is, the OP didn't _ask_ for trimmed strings in the result.  _As the question is phrased_, it's a duplicate of the other.   If the requirement included trimmed spaces, then the OP always has the option to edit the question, at which point it might be reopened.  Second-guessing the requirements and intent of a question-asker is useful sometimes, but sometimes its the path to unhelpful answers.

Comment: As the OP does not accept any of the given answers (every answers are same and similar to _original marked_ question), OP might not satisfy with the given answers or he didn't get a solution for his requirement.

Answer (score 355):

```
var partsOfStr = str.split(',');
```

[`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: @Andrew That's an entirely different question. Please read this one again.

Comment: remove any garbage (") server-side before its presented to JS

Comment: & you can use `.join()` to put them back together again

Comment: @alex what if I have in str `{a: 'a'}` how can I stop the split function to split this object, and only work on a list of elements?

Comment: fails miserably when a field value contains a comma. obviously.

Answer (score 117):

```
var array = string.split(',')
```

and good morning, too, since I have to type 30 chars ...

Answer (score 109):

```js
var result;
result = "1,2,3".split(","); 
console.log(result);
```

More info on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) describing the String Split function.

Comment: Parse result like this `"val1 with extra, here",val2,val3`

Comment: @Andrew The code will work perfectly to do that. If you want code to split on `,` and take into account quoted values, ask a new question :)

Answer (score 29):

Use

```
YourCommaSeparatedString.split(',');
```