# How can I put the individual words of a string in a javascript array?

Tags: javascript

I need to put the words of a text area into a JavaScript array. I've got it working right up to the crucial point. I've written a function to count the words, but that didn't really help as I need to count the words by using `array.length` or whatever the property may be.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Test Form</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <textarea cols="80" rows="15"  id="words" name="words">
    </textarea>
    <br/> 
    <br/> 
    <br/> 
    <br/> 

    <script>
        function get_words()
        {
            var x = document.getElementById("words").value;
            return x;
        }

        function put_words_into_array() 
        {
            var w = get_words(); 
            var a = /// need code here to put words of the string into array
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: Parsing english is even more impossible than parsing xml… O.O

Comment: Use the split command, have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5269894/1500022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, use the split function.

```
function to_array()
{
    var words = document.getElementById('words').value;
    var words_arr = words.split(' '); // here is the array
    alert(words_arr);
}
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/X5x6P/1/

Answer (score 2):

You could split it on groups of nonword characters:

```
var a = w.split(/\W+/);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `split` function:

```
function get_words() {
    var x = document.getElementById("words").value;
    return x.split(' '); // Returns an array with each word.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_words(){
     var str = document.getElementById("words").value;
     return str.split(" ");
}

alert(get_words().length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the JavaScript "split" command:

```
var a = "1 2 3".split(" ");
```

This will result in the array a, having this content: ["1", "2", "3"]
And keep in mind that the split function interprets it's parameter as a regular expression, when you use different separators.