# How to read comma seperated value in xml using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

How to read the csv in js from like these
and process the right answer to grade 
note: the answers are included in the xml and are seperated by commas

```xml
<finalquiz>
<question>  
<qnumber>1</qnumber>  
<qtitle>what is 2+2 </qtitle>  
<a>4</a>  
<b>6</b>  
<c>2</c>  
<d>0</d>  
</question>  
<question>  
<qnumber>2</qnumber>  
<qtitle>what is 3+3 </qtitle>  
<a>4</a>  
<b>6</b>  
<c>9</c>  
<d>3</d>  
<rightanswers>a,b</rightanswers>  
</finalquiz>
```

Comment: That is a weird CSV file. So read the text from the xml tag and split it on the comma https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269856/how-to-split-comma-separated-string-using-javascript

Comment: But the problem is how to do i read rightanswers into js, i am able to read the question and options and even put radio buttons on it, but not able to process answers

Comment: Looks like you need an xml-parser

Comment: i used it and i am able to read it as string, Thanks !! , should i use split and make a grade function ? Can you explain a bit on that?

Comment: If you can post the string you have as part of your question, it will be easier for us to suggest solutions.

Comment: var answer="";
  answer +=  xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("rightanswers")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;   // this is what i have to read right answer the string is : "a,b"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been discussed in the comments, you have already parsed the XML and have a string containing the values you need, separated by commas.  So the hard work is all done.  The solution at this point is very easy - just use "split" to separate the string on the commas.  Something like this:

```
var rightAnswersString = "a,b"; // Assume you have come up with something like this by parsing the XML
var rightAnswersArray = rightAnswersString.split (",");
for (let i=0; i<rightAnswersArray.length; i++) {
   console.log (rightAnswersArray[i]); // Replace console.log with whatever you need to do with each value
}
```