# How to insert comma after every number in Redux Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, redux-form

I am trying to take input from the user and insert commas after every number. For example if the user types `12345` I want the result to be `1,2,3,4,5`. Could someone please help me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269856/how-to-split-comma-separated-string-using-javascript

Comment: it actually work for me but it just add comma to number, I want comma in alphabetic too . `value && value.replace(/\B(?=(\d{1})+(?!\d))/g, ","); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

```js
const str = "12345";
const res = [...str].join();
console.log(res);
```

Comment: it actually work for me but it just add comma to number, I want comma in alphabetic too . `value && value.replace(/\B(?=(\d{1})+(?!\d))/g, ","); `

Comment: @Jonas What do you mean by that?

Comment: @hav1 . I mean to say that it add comma to the end of every character but it just work for number , I want to add comma in alphabetic character tooo

Comment: @Jonas How does it not work for alphabetic characters? https://jsfiddle.net/wrgkq32d/

Comment: Could you please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62941948/how-to-add-event-listener-to-redux-form

Answer (score 1):

this example will help understand how to split the value entered

```js
r = document.getElementById("result")
btn = document.getElementById("btn")

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  v = document.getElementById("values").value
  var splitv = v.split("").join(",")
  console.log(splitv)
  r.textContent = splitv
})
```

```html
<label>enter values</label>
<input id="values" />
<div id="result"></div>
<br>
<button id=btn>result</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert it onBlur or onSubmit

```js
function addCommas (num) {
  return num.toString().split("").join(",");
}

console.log(addCommas(12345));
```

Comment: Actually , it work but I need to be use it in redux form . Could you please help me

Comment: it actually work for me but it just add comma to number, I want comma in alphabetic too . 

`value && value.replace(/\B(?=(\d{1})+(?!\d))/g, ",");`