# How to add event listener to redux form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am trying to pass the `keydown` event to redux form but I am at a loss. Could some one please help me how to resolve this issue? Actually, I want to alert when user hit enter in redux form.

```html
<div className="col-sm-3">
  <Field
    name={`${item}.value`}
    type="text"
    component={renderField}
    keyDown={() => alert("what ar eyou")}
    normalize={normalizeDropdown}
    label="Values"
  />
</div>
```

Comment: @Mr. Poylwhirl . Will you please help me ?

Comment: What is the behaviour now? Are you getting alert on every key press?

Comment: @RohanAgarwal Actually , when user hit enter I want to alert . I did in JavaScript but did not able to do it in `redux-form`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Field
    name={`${item}.value`}
    type="text"
    component={renderField}
    onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e)}
    normalize={normalizeDropdown}
    label="Values"
  />
```

---

```
const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
if(e.key == "Enter") {
alert("How are you?")
}
}
```

Comment: What is it that's not working?Like isn't the handleKeyDown function firing up? Or is it some other error/warning that you are getting?

Comment: Yes, function has not been firing

Comment: Updated answer. Please check