# How to get an array from a csv column. Js

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

im new to js, have two question about how to parse a csv, i have a simple csv with two column, `column1:'user', column2:'amount'`

1. how can i get one array with all the 'user' column value and one
   array with all the 'amount' column value?
2. And can i loop trough the rows and use index to get the
   value of the two column? something like `csv['amount'][0] or csv[0][1]` or something like this?

ty.

Comment: Would you show a sample csv file here?

Comment: what do you mean ? it's a csv with 2 column as i said column1 with users so strings with usernames and second columns with amount, with int prices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, declare 2 arrays, one for `user`, one for `amount`.

And then read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156501/read-a-file-one-line-at-a-time-in-node-js) post to know how to read a file line by line.

After that, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269856/how-to-split-comma-separated-string-using-javascript) post to know how to split a string with a comma separator.

Finally, use the array.push() method to push the data into an array.